# What describes best the term "Memory Footprint"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

In the terms of Apple's Documentation: What does "Memory Footprint" mean? How much Memory my App consumes? Does someone have a good explanation for that term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's one explanation:
[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_footprint)

Answer (score 2):

The memory footprint of an application can be described as how much memory it uses at the point when it uses the most memory.

Comment: Like the Big O notation for Space complexity?